# jQuery Ajax setTimeout in beforeSend function during submit form

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have contact form created by PHP and ajax. I want when I click on `Send Message` button change button text to `Sending...` within `beforeSend` function. I want setting time to button until show me `Sending...` text about 5 seconds. I Created setTimeout function as below but don't work

**Edit Code** only i add some conditional statements within myd `done` function and i added some code within `complete` function

```
(function (jQuery, window, document, undefined) {
'use strict';

jQuery('#contactForm').submit(function(event) {

    var bsnname = jQuery('#bsnname').val();
    var bsnsubject = jQuery('#bsnsubject').val();
    var bsnemail = jQuery('#bsnemail').val();
    var bsnmessage = jQuery('#bsnmessage').val();

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/wp/wp-content/plugins/Yallanpe-BSN/inc/class-contact-inc.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'bsnname': bsnname, 'bsnsubject': bsnsubject, 'bsnemail': bsnemail, 'bsnmessage': bsnmessage},
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        if (!data.success) {
            if(data.errors.nameEmpty) {
                jQuery('#name-field').append('<em class="text-danger">' + data.errors.nameEmpty + '</em>');
            } else {
                jQuery('#name-field .text-danger').fadeOut(25);
                if(data.errors.nameLengthErrors) {
                    jQuery('#name-field').append('<em class="text-danger">' + data.errors.nameLengthErrors + '</em>');
                }
            }
            if(data.errors.subjectEmpty) {
                jQuery('#subject-field').append('<em class="text-danger">' + data.errors.subjectEmpty + '</em>');
            } else {
                jQuery('#subject-field .text-danger').fadeOut(25);
                if(data.errors.subjectLengthErrors) {
                    jQuery('#subject-field').append('<em class="text-danger">' + data.errors.subjectLengthErrors + '</em>');
                }
            }
            if(data.errors.emailEmpty) {
                jQuery('#email-field').append('<em class="text-danger">' + data.errors.emailEmpty + '</em>');
            } else {
                jQuery('#email-field .text-danger').fadeOut(25);
                if(data.errors.emailFormatErrors) {
                    jQuery('#email-field').append('<em class="text-danger">' + data.errors.emailFormatErrors + '</em>');
                }
            }
            if(data.errors.messageEmpty) {
                jQuery('#message-field').append('<em class="text-danger">' + data.errors.messageEmpty + '</em>');
            } else {
                jQuery('#message-field .text-danger').fadeOut(25);
                if(data.errors.messageLengthErrors) {
                    jQuery('#message-field').append('<em class="text-danger">' + data.errors.messageLengthErrors + '</em>');
                }
            }
        } else {
                jQuery('#success-msg').append('<p class="bg-success">Message has been sent</p>');
        }

    })
    .fail(function(data) {
    });

    jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
        document.getElementById("contactForm").reset();
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
}(jQuery, window, document));
```

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you are doing. But setTimeout will delay the change by five seconds, which seems odd to want to do. I would have the button change to sending inside beforeSend and then use a callback of the ajax request to change it to sent or something.

Comment: I want when i click on Send message button change the text for the Sending... show it for about 5 seconds after that show the success message.(Success message work with me correctly but i want delay it for about 5 seconds)

Comment: Why wouldn't you just change the text as soon as the response goes through? What you are looking for would be to set the button text to sending... as you have in your code without the timeout, then have a settimeout that changes it back after exactly five seconds.

Comment: Oh if have errors also show Sending... text. If you can help me and edit my code. I want show Sending... text if all things ok, and don't have any errors. please if you can edit my code and solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `beforeSend`. Just wrap the AJAX function inside the `setTimeout` callback function as shown below.

```
jQuery('button').text("Sending...");

setTimeout(function () {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/wp/wp-content/plugins/Yallanpe-BSN/inc/class-contact-inc.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'bsnname': bsnname, 'bsnsubject': bsnsubject, 'bsnemail': bsnemail, 'bsnmessage': bsnmessage},
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            // Some code here work correctly
        },
        error: function () {
            // Some bug messages
        },
        complete: function () {
            // good place to change the button back to its original text
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```

But the biggest question you should ask yourself is: what's the point of doing this? You just want to delay the request to change the text of the button.

**Edit:** Here's a quick [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8j81fq8z/) of what I think you want.

Comment: Your code show Sending... text in success and error message cases but i want show the Sending... text during success case means when not have any error within my contact form

Comment: No i want when i click on Sending message and everything within my contact form is OK (means not have any error like empty fields) then change text for 5 seconds then show success message like this Thank you your message has sent.

Comment: That means you need to validate your form before making the AJAX request i.e. use JavaScript to validate your fields. If everything is good, then do the above.

Comment: [jQuery validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) may be of some use for you.

Comment: thank you for reply your demo code work but i edit my code until help you for understand me I added codes within done function and within compete function my code work correctly. now only i want help me when not have any errors change Send message button to Sending.... for about 5 seconds then show success message. please i want solve my problem on my code

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to show _Sending..._ when you are actually sending the message. That is not possible with your current code because the client-side code does not when you are actually sending the message. In order to do what you want is make two ajax request: (1) for checking for errors and (2) for sending the message. In the `success` or `done` callback function of (1), you would do (2) using the initial code I wrote in my answer.

Comment: But again, I would advise not to do this because it accomplishes nothing. You are making an extra request just so that you can show _Sending..._. It's better to do validation on the client-side (as shown in the demo) and then make one request to send the message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111061/discussion-between-shwan-namiq-and-mikey).

Answer (score 0):

The beforeSend in Ajax is meant to do what you want : display a message while the jax call is being processed.

It is confusing for the user to have a message saying it is loading whereas the result is already there.

I don't think you should use the setTimeout function in that case ...

Answer (score 0):

A far better strategy would be to only show the loading if a `x` amount of time has passed. The user then experiences instant gratification without any glitchy flash of the pre-loader if their connection/download is fast and is notified properly on slower connections.

```
const url = 'https://555'
const data = {foo: bar}
const preloaderTimeout

$.ajax({
  url,
  data,
  beforeSend: () => {
    preloaderTimeout = setTimeout(showLoader, 500)
  },
  success: (data) => {
    clearTimeout(preloaderTimeout)
    ...do stuff w/data
  }
})
```